# Show multiple selection with 3 columns in MYSQL and values NULL

Tags: php, mysql, join, count, row

I have these 2 tables:

pupils:

```
id_pupil
name
surname
email
user
pass
level
class
```

incidents:

```
id_incidents
date
time
type_incident(miss, delay or attitude)
comments
id_pupil
id_user
subject
id_trimester
```

And i would like to get this:

[image]

I write this:

```
select pupils.id_pupil, name, surname, count(type_incident) as misses 
from pupils left join incidents using (id_pupil) 
where type_incident='miss' and level=1 and class='B' and id_trimester=1 
group by id_pupil
```

and i get the column with the misses of each pupil. However, i don´t get the null values, because i want to get also the pupils with 0 misses.

The same with delays and attitude:

```
select pupils.id_pupil, name, surname, count(type_incident) as misses 
from pupils left join incidents using (id_pupil) 
where type_incident='delay' and level=1 and class='B' and id_trimester=1 
group by id_pupil

select pupils.id_pupil, name, surname, count(type_incident) as misses 
from pupils left join incidents using (id_pupil) 
where type_incident='attitude' and level=1 and class='B' and id_trimester=1 
group by id_pupil
```

And i want to get all in a same table as described on picture.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put you conditions in a `sum()`. It sums up how many times your condition was true (`1`)

```
select pupils.id_pupil, name, surname, 
       sum(type_incident='miss' and level=1 and class='B' and id_trimester=1) as misses,
       sum(type_incident='delay' and level=1 and class='B' and id_trimester=1) as delays,
       sum(type_incident='attitude' and level=1 and class='B' and id_trimester=1) as attitudes
from pupils 
left join incidents using (id_pupil) 
group by id_pupil, name, surname
```

### [SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c5758/1)

Comment: It returns 0 in all fields :(

Comment: I wrote this but it shows same: select pupils.id_pupil, name, surname, 
       sum(case when type_incident='miss' and level=1 and class='B' and id_trimester=1 then 1 else 0 end) as misses,
       sum(case when type_incident='delay' and level=1 and class='B' and id_trimester=1 then 1 else 0 end) as delays,
       sum(case when type_incident='attitude' and level=1 and class='B' and id_trimester=1 then 1 else 0 end) as attitudes
from pupils 
left join incidents using (id_pupil) 
group by id_pupil, name, surname

Comment: However, it doesn´t work... I don´t understand where is the problem

Comment: Yes, you´re right, it works perfectly. Another question? How can i get 0 instead NULL?

Comment: Not sure what you mean but you can always use a case: `when some_column is null then 0 else some_column end`

Answer (score 1):

I think juergen's answer would be better than mine as the code is more readable, but since I was already typing mine out I'll go ahead and post another way to achieve the same result: My original two suggestions were to add `name` and `surname` to your GROUP BY statement; also, move the condition `and id_trimester=1` from WHERE up into your LEFT JOIN, so something like this:

```
select p.id_pupil, name, surname, count(i.type_incident) as misses, count(i2.type_incident) as delays, count(i3.type_incident) as attitudes
from pupils p
left join incidents i on i.id_pupil = p.id and i.type_incident='miss' and i.id_trimester=1
left join incidents i2 on i2.id_pupil = p.id and i2.type_incident='delay' and i2.id_trimester=1
left join incidents i3 on i3.id_pupil = p.id and i3.type_incident='attitude' and i3.id_trimester=1
where p.level=1 and p.class='B'
group by p.id_pupil, name, surname
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT CONCAT(p.name, ' ', p.surname) AS Pupil, t1.misses, t2.delays, t3.attitude
FROM pupils AS p
LEFT JOIN (SELECT COUNT(*) AS misses FROM id_incidents WHERE type_incident = 'miss' and level=1 and class='B' and id_trimester=1) AS t1 ON (t1.id_user = p.id_pupil)
LEFT JOIN (SELECT COUNT(*) AS delays FROM id_incidents WHERE type_incident = 'delay' and level=1 and class='B' and id_trimester=1) AS t2 ON (t2.id_user = p.id_pupil)
LEFT JOIN (SELECT COUNT(*) AS attitude FROM id_incidents WHERE type_incident = 'attitude' and level=1 and class='B' and id_trimester=1) AS t3 ON (t3.id_user = p.id_pupil)
```